# Python/Pygame character flashing rapidly

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm making a small game using PyGame, and my character keeps flashing rapidly when I run the game, and I can't figure out why. Can someone please help me out? Here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys, time, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hunter vs. Hunter")

keys = [False, False, False, False]
shirtpos = [330,270]
pantspos = [342,322]
helmpos = [349,230]
bowpos = [395,248]
invcounter = 0
arrows=[]

bkdrop = pygame.image.load("Resources\grassybackdrop.gif")
helm = pygame.image.load("Resources\mainhelm.gif")
shirt = pygame.image.load("Resources\mainshirt.gif")
pants = pygame.image.load("Resources\mainpants.gif")
inv = pygame.image.load("Resources\invdisplay.gif")
bow = pygame.image.load("1bow.gif")
arrow = pygame.image.load("arrow.gif")
screen.blit(bkdrop, (0,0))


while 1:
    screen.blit(helm, helmpos)
    screen.blit(shirt, shirtpos)
    screen.blit(pants, pantspos)
    screen.blit(bow, bowpos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(shirtpos[1]+32),position[0]-(shirtpos[0]+26)),shirtpos[0]+32,shirtpos[1]+32])

        for bullet in arrows:
            index=0
            velx=math.cos(bullet[0])*10
            vely=math.sin(bullet[0])*10
            bullet[1]+=velx
            bullet[2]+=vely
            if bullet[1]<-64 or bullet[1]>640 or bullet[2]<-64 or bullet[2]>480:
                arrows.pop(index)
            index+=1
            for projectile in arrows:
                arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360-projectile[0]*57.29)
                screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:   
            if event.key == K_w:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key == K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key == K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key == K_d:
                keys[3]=True
            elif event.key == K_TAB:
                screen.blit(inv, (147,96))
                invcounter+=1


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key == K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key == K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key == K_d:
                keys[3]=False


    if invcounter % 2 == 0:
        if keys[0] == True:
            shirtpos[1]-=2.5
            pantspos[1]-=2.5
            helmpos[1]-=2.5
            bowpos[1]-=2.5
        if keys[1] == True:
            shirtpos[0]-=2.5
            pantspos[0]-=2.5
            helmpos[0]-=2.5
            bowpos[0]-=2.5
        if keys[2] == True:
            shirtpos[1]+=2.5
            pantspos[1]+=2.5
            helmpos[1]+=2.5
            bowpos[1]+=2.5
        if keys[3] == True:
            shirtpos[0]+=2.5
            pantspos[0]+=2.5
            helmpos[0]+=2.5
            bowpos[0]+=2.5
        if pantspos[1] > 386:
            pantspos[1] = 386
            shirtpos[1] = 336
            helmpos[1] = 296
            bowpos[1] = 310


    if invcounter % 2 == 0:
        screen.blit(bkdrop, (0,0))

    pygame.display.flip()

    fpsClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: If your images are flashing while drawing them that's a tip off that you might have to do double buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're flipping the screen twice. Once right after you draw the objects, and again near the bottom of the loop.

Additionally you appear to have blits which correspond to event.keydown type things. Not sure if these are your actual player sprite objects or other ancillary things, but ideally I don't think you want to handle any blitting there - you just want to change the state of your objects (and I don't necessarily mean 'make a state machine' if you're not writing one, I just mean - handle the event here... draw it later)

Ideally a 'dummy loop' for PyGame would resemble something like this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # handle events

    MyScreenObject.fill((0, 0, 0)) # or whatever background you're using
    VisibleObjectGroup.draw() # draw all objects that can be seen in a sprite.Group -- use these and love these, they're loaded with good things
    pygame.display.flip() #call this ONE time per loop
    MyFPSClock.tick(FPS)
```

I mean there's no collision checks there or anything, but this is the idea, ultimately -- don't update the screen until after events are processed.

Comment: Alright, thanks Stick! I'll try editing my code a little bit to match your suggestions. Thank you for the suggestion about fixing the event.keydown blitting issue. I'll change that up and see how it works. Once I get back to my home machine, I'll try these fixes. Thanks again!